# How to delete Not null constraint in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database created in phpmyadmin named inventory and table inside it named inventorydb.

My question is, how do I delete `not null` columns. the thing is I already set it to `not null` in phpMyAdmin. here's my coding.

```
("DELETE FROM inventorydb WHERE item_id= ('"+jTextField19.getText()+"') AND item_id IS NOT NULL");
```

I'm using java netbeans. I want an error to popup when the field is blank, btw item_id is my primary key. Sorry I'm quite new in all of this.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but please use PreparedStatements for sql queries. It's quite unsafe to build sql queries concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key 3 properties

```
i) Not Null
ii) Unique
iii) auto-indexing
```

So your `item_id` must not be empty. **You must define values**. Then your query will be look like below:

```
int rowsDeleted = DELETE FROM inventorydb WHERE item_id= ('"+jTextField19.getText()+"');
if (rowsDeleted > 0) {
    // give success message using JOptionPane
    System.out.println("A user was deleted successfully!");
} else {
 // give error message
}
```

Comment: i've tried it this way, but still when i press delete with no id keyed in, it still runs with no error.

Comment: @HafizKhairul Have you put value in your textfield `jTextField19`. If you give the exact value, then it will delete. I am not clear about your concern. Would you please clarify me?

Comment: yes it does, i get the delete working properly but what i want to know is, how to set an error when the user left the jTextField19 field blank or fill it with a value that is not found in the database.

Comment: @HafizKhairul I have updated my answer. Please check it. Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: @HafizKhairul Please let me know if any problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can `jTextField19.getText()` value in string and then put null check on it.

```
String value = jTextField19.getText();
if (value == null || "".equals(value)) {
   // Write your popup code here
}
```

Then your delete query can come in else part or as per your logic.

```
DELETE FROM inventorydb WHERE item_id= ('"+jTextField19.getText()+"');
```

No need to put extra is `null` check.

Comment: Thank you man, this work fine, but what if the user enter an ID input which is not in the database and i want an error to pop up?